# Detect a click on document but ignore specific element(s)

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Currently I have a popup window.

I want to hide this popup when clicking anywhere except on links `<a>` and buttons `<button>`.

Can I add event listeners to `document` and ignore these 2 elements?

I tried the following, but it's not working properly:

```js
(function($) {

  $(document).on('click', ':not(a, button)', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
  });

  /* Other option, also not working properly
  $( document ).not( 'a, button' ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log( event.target.nodeName );
  } );
  */

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 35px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="link">I'm a link</a>
  <button>I'm a button</button>
</div>
```

Options I am aware about but still feels wrong:

Use an if statement like so:

```
 if( event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'a' or event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'button' ) {
      // Do w/e I want to
 }
```

Or stop the propagation using:

```
$( 'a, button' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
} );
```

Comment: just use `$('a,button').click(function() {
            return false;
      });`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have ask if the `event.target` is an `a` or `button` like this:

`if (!$(event.target).closest("a, button").length)`

Hope this helps you.

```js
(function($) {

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest("a, button").length) {
      console.log(event.target.nodeName);
    }

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 35px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="link">I'm a link</a>
  <button>I'm a button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You know you are getting `element` from `event.target.nodeName`, then just check if it is either `A` or `BUTTON` and if yes, just `return`

```js
(function($) {

  $(".container").on('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target.nodeName=='A' || event.target.nodeName=='BUTTON')
      return;
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 35px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="link">I'm a link</a>
  <button>I'm a button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your question is as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest("a, button").length) {
      if(event.target.nodeName=="A"||event.target.nodeName=="BUTTON"){
     //DON'T DO ANY THING
      }
      else{
     //SHOW THE POPUP
     }

    }

  });
Hope this helps!!!!!
```